# What happens when you write to a register with the same configuration?

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, stm32

I'm working with the STM32L432KC and am relatively new to the embedded world.  What happens if I write to a configuration register, wait some time, and then write to the register again with the same configuration.  Does this have any effects?

For reference, I am using the STM32L432KC microcontroller.  The register in question is the Reset and Clock Control (RCC), AHB2 Peripheral Clock Enable Register (RCC_AHB2ENR).  I have a function that enables the clock for a GPIO port, by OR'ing in a bit.  I am wondering if calling the function while the pin is active will have any effects.

Comment: That may depend on how you've wired your board, whether you've locked the configuration, and the exact phase of the clock.  Glitches are possible.  Read the data sheet, extrapolate as needed: https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32l432kc.pdf

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks.

Comment: it depends specifically on the chip, bit, design.  some writing a bit causes an action every write even if values dont change.  the clock enables though are meant to be read-modify-write so only the bits that change will cause some action.  if enabled a write again with the same bits enabled will not glitch or change the peripheral that enable is tied to for that family of chips and that register.

Comment: @jwdonahue it is not the truth.

Comment: Put a scope on the pin.

Comment: @jwdonahue I would advice to first read the STM documentaion, then discuss and argue. Datasheet is far not enough when we talk about those uCs. read Reference & programming manuals

Comment: You're right, I should have said RTFM.  The data sheet doesn't have enough information on it, and it certainly doesn't cover this aspect.

Comment: @jwdonahue datasheet does not cover almost anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no generic answer for all registers on all devices.  The only correct course is to consult the data sheet or reference manual for the part concerned.

In the specific case of [STM32L432](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/group0/b0/ac/3e/8f/6d/21/47/af/DM00151940/files/DM00151940.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00151940.pdf) `RCC_AHB2ENR` all *used* bits are specified as "*set and cleared by software*" with no specific hardware action on read/write.  This is true I believe for the `RCC_AHB2ENR` on all STM32.  Note however that the unused bits are *reserved* and should not be set to any value other then the *reset value* - also defined in the reference manual and in this case all zero.

Some registers change value under hardware control, so re-writing a previously written value may have an effect.  A simple example on your part is `TIM1_CNT` where if TIM1 is running the counter will have changed and rewriting it will effect its period and any capture/compare events or event output or PWM it may be used for.